# Reset input field in React (redux)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I am making a basic Todo application using redux, this is my first time using these methods of redux. I have a problem when I add the Todo the input field does not reset, I have tried various approaches and non seem to work.

For example: defaultValue, handleText on click to bring it back to an empty string, etc.

There are similar question on stack but non with my approach. Here is my code.

[image]

Reducer:
[image]

Comment: Don't post screen shots of code. All code samples should be included in your question _as text_. Images are not searchable, and others can't copy the content and run your code or edit your code in their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reset the value of the input field, you just need to set the state value of `todos` to an empty string, which you would do by calling:

```
setTodos('');
```

As you want to do that following the click, you can call `setTodos` following to the `dispatch` in the `handleClick` function:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  dispatch({ ... });
  setTodos('');
};
```

Additionally, you might want to initialize `todos` to a empty string instead of an array as it is used as a value for a text input:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState('');
```

Comment: after I use this method this error pops up: TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function

Comment: I have updated the code snippet as dispatch does not return a promise.

Comment: ./src/components/todo.js
SyntaxError: /Users/faruksuljagic/Desktop/redux-app/src/components/todo.js: Identifier 'handleClick' has already been declared. (36:10) >>>> const handleClick = () => {
        dispatch({ type: "ADD_TODO",
        payload: {
            label: todos,
            id: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)
        });
        setTodos('');
      };

Comment: It was a mistake on my end, i fixed your code a bit  const handleClick = () => {
        dispatch({ type: "ADD_TODO",
        payload: {
            label: todos,
            id: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)
        },});
        setTodo('');
      }; and now it works like a charm, thank you very much!